# Python loop doesn't work with readlines()

Tags: python, arrays, file, for-loop, readlines

It suppose to count amount of "-------------------------" lines but it doesn't work, also line with print("test") doesn't shows in console and it always returns 0. But for example line print("hi") works. Program just cannot see my loop and I have no idea why. :(

```
def check_id():
    with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        ad = 0
                print("hi")  # This line works
        for i in lines:
            print("test")  # This line doesn't work
            if i == "-------------------------":
                ad += 1

        return str(ad)
```

if I need to send full code to solve the problem just ask

I changed mode 'a+' to 'r' so that it can read lines correctly, and it does, but I still can't check array to get amount of this lines. If you have any guesses or solutions write it please.

Edited: Here is my whole code of data.py and text in file data.txt

```
from datetime import date
date = date.today()


def write_note(line):
    with open('data.txt', 'a') as f:
        if line == "!quit":
            f.write('\n')
            f.write("-------------------------")
            f.write('\n')
            ad = check_id()
            f.write(ad)
            f.write('\n')
            f.write("________________________")
            f.write('\n')
        else:
            f.write(line)
            f.write("\n")


def read_note(id):
    with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
        pass


def see_all():
    with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
        get_lines = f.readlines()
        for i in get_lines:
            print(i)
        return get_lines


def del_note(ad):
    with open('data.txt', 'a') as f:
        pass


def logs():
    pass


def check_id():
    with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
        ad = 0
        for i in f:
            if i == "-------------------------":
                ad += 1

        return str(ad)
```

and now txt file:

```
fugy
hello
hai
bebra

-------------------------
0
________________________
uha
imna
fsjfoe
geso;rsevdn

-------------------------
0  # This one
________________________
```

I'm trying to make notebook so that it's possible to write notes and read them. Delete func i'll do after. Idea is to make this zeros bigger each time I add note.

Comment: Print len(lines). What do you get?

Comment: Works fine for me (after fixing that first `print("hi")` indention error). On a 6 line file, it printed "hi", then "test" 6 times, then "0" since I didn't have any lines with dashes like that.

Comment: Your file is empty.  Even if it wasn't empty, your count wouldn't work, because none of the lines (except maybe the very last one) can possibly match the string you're comparing them to - they will end with a newline character.  Applying `.strip()` to the line before comparing it would be one possible solution.

Comment: Each line will include the closing newline.  You need to check if `i == "-------\n"`.   And please don't name a string variable `i`.  Your code will read a lot better as `for line in lines:`

Comment: print("hi") is not with the proper indentation. I dont know how it works. `if i == "-------------------------":` should be replaced with `if i == "-------------------------\n":`

Comment: Don't use `readlines` here at all; you only ever work with one line at a time, which you can get by iterating over the file directly with `for i in f: ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with your `data.txt` file (Probably it's empty, because you mentioned the `"test"` is not visible in the console, it means the script doesn't run in the `for` loop, in other word: the length of `lines` iterator is zero).

I have written a working code, you can see below the code and the test file with the output of script.

**Code:**

```py
def check_id():
    with open('data.txt', 'r') as opened_file:
        ad = 0
        print("hi")  # This line works
        for i in opened_file:
            print("test")  # This line doesn't work
            if i == "-------------------------":
                ad += 1
        return str(ad)


result = check_id()
print(f"Result: {result}")
```

**Content of `data.txt`:**

```
test_1
-------------------------
test_2
-------------------------
test_3
-------------------------
test_4
```

**Test:**

```
> python3 test.py 
hi
test
test
test
test
test
test
test
Result: 0
```

**EDIT:**

The OP shared the complete source code and the used `data.txt` which contains `cr` `lf` characters ([Details about that chars](https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/crlf)). It means the lines have to be striped with `rstrip` method.

In this case only the `check_id` function is related so I share only that modified function:

```py
def check_id():
    with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
        ad = 0
        for i in f:
            # The cr and lf characters should be removed from line. Please see the above reference for details.
            if i.rstrip() == "-------------------------":
                ad += 1
        return str(ad)


result = check_id()
print(result). # Result is 4
```

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your edit. You have to add `i.rstrip()` to remove the `cr` `lf` characters from end of lines.

Answer (score 0):

YAY, I decided to ask Chat-GPT3 and it helped me! Correct version is:

```
def check_id():
    with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
        ad = 0
        for i in f:
            if i.strip() == "-------------------------":
                ad += 1

        return str(ad)
```

Thanks everyone for your attention!